# Recommended patterns for writing asynchronous evented servers in C

Tags: c, asynchronous, libevent

I am writing my first single-threaded, single-process server in C using kqueue() / epoll() to handle asynchronous event dispatch. As one would expect, it is quite a lot harder to follow the flow of control than in a blocking server.

Is there a common pattern (maybe even with a name) that people use to avoid the callback-driven protocol implementation becoming a gigantic tangled hairball?

Alternately, are there any nonblocking servers written in C for which the source code is a pleasure to read?

Any input would be much appreciated!

More thoughts:

A lot of the cruft seems to come from the need to deal with the buffering of IO. There is no necessary correspondence between a buffer filling/draining and a single state transition. A buffer fill/drain might correspond to [0, N] state transitions.)

I've looked at libev ([docs here](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod)) and it looks like a great tool, and libevent, which looks less exciting but still useful, but neither of them really answers the question: how do I manage the flow of control in a way that isn't horrendously opaque.

Comment: Not so clear on what you are looking for, when you create an event based system you convert everything into events so you have the same basic interface which drastically simplifies everything.

Comment: There are IO events, and there are protocol events (state changes). Consider the case of a socket-based server. An IO event means "your fd is ready for read (write)". A protocol event might say something like "the client would like to change your state from AWAITING_AUTH to AUTH_STARTED". However, we require data before we can move from AWAITING_AUTH->AUTH_STARTED. In the case of a blocking server, no big; we just block until we've got the data. In the asynchronous case, we need to keep running the event loop until we've got the required data, then trigger the state transition.

Comment: I can do this, but not in a way that approaches the code transparency of a blocking server. I'm wondering if there are standard approaches, or good code samples. For an example, I'm looking at [prot.c](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/7c50a06309f1faceebab73bef61206020a0bc6f9/prot.c) from beanstalkd - it isn't the easiest thing in the world to follow.

Comment: I guess using continuations would help a lot here, but then I'm going to have to find a portable continuations library... blergh.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using something like [State Threads](http://state-threads.sourceforge.net/) or [GNU Portable Threads](http://www.gnu.org/software/pth/), which allows you to write as though you were using a single thread per connection (The implementation uses [Fibers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29)).

Alternately, you can build your protocol implementation using a state machine generator (such as [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/)).